# Firebase Simple Login + Angular - Own data for each user

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

This is my controller. Register function works ok. Login doesn't, but my question is, how can I make data for each user? For example, I have user john@doe.cz, UID is simplelogin:29, ID 29. Each user will have own accounts, categories, etc. So what is the best practice or how can I make it happen? I think about making own-firebase.firebaseio.com/users/(id, uid, or some kind of hash)/categories or accounts.

```
app.controller('AuthCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $firebase, DataFactory){

    var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(usersAuth, function(error, user) {
        if (error) {
            // an error occurred while attempting login
            console.log(error);
        } else if (user) {
            // user authenticated with Firebase
            console.log('User ID: ' + user.uid + ', Provider: ' + user.provider);
        } else {
            // user is logged out
        }
    });

    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('views/auth/register.html', function(modal) {
        $scope.registerModal = modal;
    }, {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
    });

    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('views/auth/login.html', function(modal) {
        $scope.loginModal = modal;
    }, {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
    });

    $scope.registerModalShow = function() {
        $scope.registerModal.show();
    };

    $scope.registerModalHide = function() {
        $scope.registerModal.hide();
    };

    $scope.loginModalShow = function() {
        $scope.loginModal.show();
    };

    $scope.loginModalHide = function() {
        $scope.loginModal.hide();
    };

    $scope.newUser = function(user){
        $scope.userEmail = user.email;
        $scope.userPassword = user.password;

        auth.createUser($scope.userEmail, $scope.userPassword, function(error, user) {
            if (!error) {
                console.log('User UID: ' + user.uid + ', Email: ' + $scope.userEmail + ', User ID: ' + user.id + ', User Password: ' + $scope.userPassword);
            }
        });

        $scope.userRef = new Firebase(url + '/users' + $scope.userPassword);
        $scope.registerModalHide();
        user.email = '';
        user.password = '';
        alert($scope.userId);
    };

    $scope.userLogin = function(user){
        $scope.userLoginEmail = user.email;
        $scope.userLoginPassword = user.password;

        auth.login('password', {
            email: user.email,
            password: user.password
        });
        $scope.loginModalHide();
        user.email = '';
        user.password = '';
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following approach to create "own data for each user":

I create a new profile, which could have whatever detail I want, when someone logs in my app for first time:

```
$scope.login = function () { // This logic handle the addition of new users to my firebase.

    $rootScope.auth.$login('twitter') // Because of I'm using Twitter for login.
        .then(function (user) {
            $scope.myFirebaseRef.$child(user.uid).$set({name: user.displayName}); // Create new profile.
            console.log("Welcome " + user.displayName + "!" );
            $state.go('home');
        }, function (error) {
            consolle.log(error); 
        }
    );
}
```

Then, I perform this `resolve` when I change a view:

```
resolve: { // Basically, It's asking for a logged user and waiting for a promise before load the controller. 
  session: function($rootScope) {
    return $rootScope.auth.$getCurrentUser().then(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        $rootScope.someCurrentUser = user.uid;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Finally, I use `$rootScope.someCurrentUser` to create a personalized session:

```
.controller('sessionController', ['$rootScope', '$firebase', function($rootScope, $firebase) {
    var someUserRef = new Firebase('https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com/' + $rootScope.someCurrentUser);
    $scope.sessionRef = $firebase(someUserRef);

    // Do something with/in your personalized session.  

}]);
```

I hope this approach gives you some ideas to create sessions/own data per user.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is a REST API so your proposed url format basically fits well.

You can use e.g. "google rest user management api" search string to Google some more tips. The "google" part in the string is there in order to find how especially "google" does it.

How Google shapes urls → https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users

Check other providers (e.g. now [abandoned](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9246846/Mozilla_stops_work_on_Persona_sign_on_to_shift_resources_to_Firefox_OS_services) "Mozilla Persona" → https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Persona) for further inspiration

Comment: But I don't want to use REST. I am using Firebase, so why REST?

Comment: @xmojmr, why REST? Kotora could do what he wants just using Firebase Javascript API.

Comment: @Jobsamuel you may be perfectly right. I don't know what Firebase can do in detail. I just tried to provide some general applicable guidelines at the time the question was asked. Thanks for your contribution I'll vote for your answer as more useful :)