# Displaying user Data from Firebase with AngularFire

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, firebase, angularfire

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I'm using AngularJS and firebase in a project where:
1. an anonymous login happens, then
2. a record in a firebase datastore gets created for that login with an ID I can retrieve, also
3. several other bits of info are added to the data structure (the user's first name and a few other things).

I want to use ng-repeat to display a number of HTMl elements that corresponds with a number associated with the user and their session. They have an opportunity to increment or decrement this amount. For example, if they have increased this number to 10, I want to use ng-repeat to display 10 HTML elements. If they decrement it to 9, display 9, etc.

The problem I'm having is in querying firebase for the record that is associated with their specific anonymous login. The firebase simple login returns a promise and I've used the firebase getCurrentUserID() method to wait and be able to retrieve the anonymous user ID for the session after it's been returned from the server.

Here's my code so far

(this is all in the controller for view at hand)

```
// wire a new Firebase connection
var ref = new Firebase('https://myfirebaseloginexample.firebaseio.com');


// connect the user object to the firebase
$scope.userRef = $firebase(ref);
// wire anonymous login
$scope.loginObj = $firebaseSimpleLogin(ref);
// wait for the anonymous login data to load and persist
$scope.loginObj.$getCurrentUser().then(function() {
  console.log($scope.loginObj.user.id);
});
```

I've been able to use the current anonymous session to query the associated data in Firebase and increment it with the following code (also in the controller)

```
// increment the number of boxes
    $scope.incrementboxCount = function() {
      // assign the session id to a variable
      var uniqueSessionChildID = $scope.loginObj.user.id;
      // pass the assigned id variable into the firebase connection, where we will find the reference with the current child (the sesison ID)
      var sessionLoc = $scope.userRef.$child(uniqueSessionChildID);
      // get the current number of boxes at the location in firebase ref specified by the session ID
      var getBoxes = sessionLoc.numberBoxes;
      // find the firebase reference that we want by ID, update it and increment the amount of boxes
      $scope.userRef.$child(uniqueSessionChildID).$update({
        numberBoxes: getBoxes + 1
      });
    };
```

the associated html:

```
<div ng-model="(not sure of proper model)">
  <div ng-repeat="box in boxes">
    <h1>How many boxes?</h1>
    <h4>{{not sure of proper express here}}</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried trying to access the loginObj data (specifically, the unique anonymous ID) so that I can query the Firebase reference, but it comes up with a null response in the stack trace. I'm guessing this is because it's being called before actually having been resolved, but I don't know how to get around that (I'm sure it's a simple fix that I'm just not getting or don't know of).

Thanks very much!

Comment: If I understand well, you are trying to fetch the current user but the controller loads before the response, which is normal when you don't use resolve, so your current user is null and you can't do anything because the rest of the logic depends of it, right?

Comment: Correct! I'm sorta new to angular and more extensive use of js (which I know is embarrassing etc. etc.) so I'm sure there's a better way to do it that I just don't know. Thanks!!

Comment: Although I should add I *can* increment and decrement the number in the firebase ref, my problem is in accessing it again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to `$scope.loginObj.user.id` return a promise, you can't expect that `var uniqueSessionChildID` immediately stores it; you need to wait and then use its response. Maybe this could solve your problem:

```
// This is wrong.
var uniqueSessionChildID = $scope.loginObj.user.id; 
var sessionLoc = $scope.userRef.$child(uniqueSessionChildID);

// This is better.
$scope.loginObj.$getCurrentUser().then(function(user) {
  if (user) { // Now, user isn't null.
    var sessionLoc = $scope.userRef.$child(user.id);

    // Here, you could do whatever you want with your session reference.

  } 
});
```

In other hand, if you want `user.id` to be available in others controllers but you don't want to ask for it each time you need it, you could use [resolve](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve). I'm going to give you an example:

```
resolve: {
  session: function($rootScope) {
    return $rootScope.loginObj.$getCurrentUser().then(function (user) {
      if (user) {
        $rootScope.anonymousUserID = user.id; // It will be injected into the controller.
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that. One more question: How would I then return the sessionLoc variable to the global scope?

Comment: You could do that using `resolve` in the controller you want the variable be. Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23683957/3366109

Comment: Got it to work! is there any way to make this more reusable? can a service be created to automatically resolve this for every controller? just doesn't seem super DRY to me.

Comment: You could use `resolve`. I just updated my response with an example.

Comment: Thanks! One thing to note, though, is that when using resolve ngmin fails; inline annotation is needed. Ran into that while building with grunt.